# Use function as an "on" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have this function:

```
function highlightBoxes() {
  var windowStart = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowEnd = windowStart + $(window).height();

  $('.box').each(function() {
    var box = $(this);
    var start = box.offset().top;
    var end = start + box.height();

    if (windowStart <= start && windowEnd >= end) {
      box.addClass('active');
    } else {
      box.removeClass('active');
    }
  });
}

highlightBoxes();
$(document).scroll(highlightBoxes);
$(window).resize(highlightBoxes);
```

Which checks if an entire element (in this case `.box`) is in view ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gr1qkeq/4/)). However, I want to be able to use the function as an on event, so I can use it for many different elements. Something like:

```
$('.box').on('inview', function () {
    if (elementIsInView) {
        // make the box red
    } else {
        // make the box the original color
    }
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: which event you want? click ,hover ,drag etc . `inview` is function .They event is  action, apply from user.

Answer (score 2):

using `on` means you will need to trigger an event with the same name, a super simple version of this is using `document` as the message bus like:

```
$(document).trigger('inview');
```

Therefore at the point in your code where you have decided that `inview` should be true, fire an event like the above, at which point the `on` event will run the function.

Base on the code above, you probably want to move the `if` statement out of the `on` event, and in fact run that as a separate function. When `elementIsInView` returns true, you could fire the `inview` event.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps me. :/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **hover** event.

```
$(document).on('hover','.box', function () {
if (elementIsInView) {
    // make the box red
} else {
    // make the box the original color
}
});
```

If am not clear with your answer let me know.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't at all what I want to do.

Comment: Please what else do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

click ,hover ,drag all are events. Event is a action, apply from user. Function is a declare with javascript.Is not directly running.Its only run after event trigger.Event are declared by w3c

I think you need something like that:

Assign function with button click.Its works from button click event.

```js
$('button').on('click',hello)

function hello(){
  console.log('button Clicked')
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button >hi</button>
```

**or**

```
$('button').on('click',function hello(){
  console.log('button Clicked')
  })
```

**For your code do like this**

```
$('.box').on('click', function inview() {
    if (elementIsInView) {
        // make the box red
    } else {
        // make the box the original color
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  function checkElementToBeInView(elem, callback) {
  $(elem).each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = element.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + element.height();
    var isInView = ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    callback(element, isInView);
  });
}
$(window).on("load resize scroll", function(e) {
  checkElementToBeInView(".box", function(elem, isInView) {
    if (isInView)
      elem.addClass('active');
    else
      elem.removeClass('active');
  });
```